# Why does f.lux use 100% of a cpu core?

Tags: cpu-load, f.lux

I installed f.lux on Ubuntu 14.04.

The GUI doesn't work properly but I am able to access settings through the xterminal. While looking in the system monitor, it can be seen that a process called "xflux" is using 100% of one one the cpu cores.

Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: You might want to try Redshift, an open source f.lux alternative: http://jonls.dk/redshift/

Comment: Same issue with Ubuntu 14.10. Redshift has no (official) UI, and the default settings are way too red.

Comment: Issue has been reported to the f.lux indicator applet author since June 2011 (https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/7).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed it. I killed the process, it restarted by itself and it works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3m21lu/question_high_cpu_usage_from_flux/) simply reinstalling F.lux solves this problem.